# How do I avoid using clone here?

Tags: image, rust

```
use rayon::prelude::*;
use image::RgbImage;


#[inline]
fn lerp(pct: f32, a: f32, b: f32) -> f32 {
    pct.mul_add(b - a, a)
}
#[inline]
fn distance(x: i32, y: i32) -> f32 {
    ((x * x + y * y) as f32).sqrt()
}

struct ColorCalculator {
    from: [f32; 3],
    to: [f32; 3],
    center_x: i32,
    center_y: i32,
    max_dist: f32,
}

impl ColorCalculator {
    fn new(from: [u8; 3], to: [u8; 3], width: u32, height: u32) -> Self {
        let center_x = width as i32 / 2;
        let center_y = height as i32 / 2;
        Self {
            from: from.map(|channel| channel as f32),
            to: to.map(|channel| channel as f32),
            center_x,
            center_y,
            max_dist: distance(center_x, center_y),
        }
    }
    fn calculate(&self, x: u32, y: u32) -> [u8; 3] {
        let x_dist = self.center_x - x as i32;
        let y_dist = self.center_y - y as i32;

        let t = distance(x_dist, y_dist) / self.max_dist;
    }
}

pub fn radial_gradient_mirror(
    geometry: [u32; 2],
    inner_color: [u8; 3],
    outer_color: [u8; 3],
) -> RgbImage {
    let [width, height] = geometry;

    let color_calculator = ColorCalculator::new(inner_color, outer_color, geometry[0], geometry[1]);

    let mut buf: Vec<_> = (0..(height / 2))
        .into_par_iter()
        .flat_map(|y| {
            let mut row: Vec<[u8; 3]> = Vec::with_capacity(width as usize);
            for x in 0..(width / 2) {
                row.push(color_calculator.calculate(x, y))
            }
            row.extend(row.clone().iter().rev());
            row
        })
        .collect();

    buf.extend(buf.clone().iter().rev());
    let buf = buf.into_iter().flatten().collect();

    RgbImage::from_raw(width, height, buf).unwrap()
}
```

I have an algorithm to generate a radial gradient. The original version would calculate the color of each pixel but because there is a horizontal and vertical line of symmetry I can calculate the colors for the top left corner and use some vector manipulation to mirror. I managed to do this by cloning and reversing the iterator `buf.clone().iter().rev()` although this is slow. How can I avoid this and are there any other optimizations I could use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not really need to populate the buffer as later you override it, you can use direct chained iterators for doing so (`copied` is used to to have owned values), original buff will be droped at the end of the scope:

```rust
let i1 = buf.iter().copied();
let i2 = buf.iter().copied().rev();
let buf = i1.chain(i2).flatten().collect();
```

Full method:

```rust
pub fn radial_gradient_mirror(
    geometry: [u32; 2],
    inner_color: [u8; 3],
    outer_color: [u8; 3],
) -> RgbImage {
    let [width, height] = geometry;

    let color_calculator = ColorCalculator::new(inner_color, outer_color, geometry[0], geometry[1]);

    let mut buf: Vec<_> = (0..(height / 2))
        .into_par_iter()
        .flat_map(|y| {
            let mut row: Vec<[u8; 3]> = Vec::with_capacity(width as usize);
            for x in 0..(width / 2) {
                row.push(color_calculator.calculate(x, y))
            }
            row.extend(row.clone().iter().rev());
            row
        })
        .collect();

    let i1 = buf.iter().copied();
    let i2 = buf.iter().copied().rev();
    let buf = i1.chain(i2).flatten().collect();

    RgbImage::from_raw(width, height, buf).unwrap()
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=64e86183cb71f78c2117515ae1af6df1)

Answer (score 0):

I believe your core question is how to optimize this:

```
buf.extend(buf.clone().iter().rev());
```

`Vec` has [`extend_from_within`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.extend_from_within) which can be used to extend a `Vec` from its own contents... however you want the results in reverse order. So I don't think there is a neat way using iterators to express this, since we're mutating and iterating over the same `Vec` at the same time. However doing this using a loop isn't too bad:

```rust
fn mirror_vec<T: Clone>(v: &mut Vec<T>) {
    let n = v.len();
    v.reserve(n);
    for i in (0..n).rev() {
        v.push(v[i].clone());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that the `clone` is not the only performance bottleneck here, and probably not the main one either. A very big issue is using a `Vec<Vec<_>>` for a 2D array. It is much faster to use a single flat array and some indexing magic:

```
pub fn radial_gradient_mirror(
    geometry: [u32; 2],
    inner_color: [u8; 3],
    outer_color: [u8; 3],
) -> RgbImage {
    let width = geometry[0] as usize;
    let height = geometry[1] as usize;

    let color_calculator = ColorCalculator::new(inner_color, outer_color, geometry[0], geometry[1]);

    // Note: need to check that dimensions are even, or handle the case when they are odd! */
    let mut buf = Vec::with_capacity (width * height * 3);
    for r in 0..height/2 {
        for c in 0..width/2 {
            buf.extend_from_slice (&color_calculator.calculate (c, r));
        }
        for c in width/2+1 .. width {
            buf.extend_from_within ((r*width + width-c-1)*3 .. (r*width + width-c)*3);
        }
    }
    for r in height/2+1 .. height {
        buf.extend_from_within ((height-r-1) * width * 3 .. (height-r) * width * 3);
    }
    
    RgbImage::from_raw(width as u32, height as u32, buf).unwrap()
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a1e907485bd3ea9b764c45e258579be3)

Note that as with all performance-related questions, you should benchmark *in release mode* to make sure that speed follows your expectations. In particular on modern computers, memory accesses are much slower than the CPU and *it is often faster to re-compute a value rather than try to get it from a cached memory location!*